# How to open your app with specific link in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, swift4, swift4.2

I'm working on an application that record video and provide an option to share that video on other apps like facebook , Instagram. so far it is working good with the posting of video but I want to share a link also so when any viewer tap on that link that will be directed to my application , can anyone guide me how to do that .

1. how to generate that link
2. how to embed it in the posting item like video and URL
3. how can I get to know that someone tried to open a link and I need to enroute it specific post
   like my post id is 1980 and I want to share it on facebook, i put the video in the item[Any] , do i need to put the URL in that list?
   and how to generate that link?
   code I'm using to share video item:

Code:

```
func launchShareActivityController(with items: [Any], of player: AVPlayer, postID: Int, canDownload: Int) {
    let shareItems: [Any] = items
    let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController.init(activityItems: shareItems, applicationActivities: nil)
    activityViewController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = self.view
    
    
    activityViewController.completionWithItemsHandler = { activity, success, items, error in
        player.play()
        if success {
            print("succesfully shared")
            self.postShare(postID: postID, completion: { (isSuccess, results) in
                if results.count > 0 {
                }
            })
        }

    }
    
}
```

Comment: the keyword for you is `deep link`
https://medium.com/wolox/ios-deep-linking-url-scheme-vs-universal-links-50abd3802f97

Comment: You can have a look at [Allowing Apps and Websites to Link to Your Content](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/inter-process_communication/allowing_apps_and_websites_to_link_to_your_content) to support **Universal Links**.

Comment: i just found the solution how to redirect a URL to my app . but now I'm facing an issue is that I have two items to share , one the file link of local storage and otherone is the post URL. but when I tap share it only one data. i mean one link either post link if I add it first or file URL if I add that first in the list . specially on facebook . how to deal with it